# Converting multiple files to STL in Solidworks 2013

Tags: vba, solidworks, stl-format

I do a lot of 3D printing, so I manually convert my part files into STL. As far as I know, Solidworks doesn't offer any features that allow you to automate this process. This said, does anyone have any suggestions as to how one may create a custom macro that would perform this function? Seems Solidworks macros are coded in VBA, which I happen to know very little of.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is plumbing the depths of my memory.

I would start by looking at the solidworks task scheduler. It may be able to do it for you.

Then maybe try recording a macro of making an STL. If you know a bit of coding it is pretty self-explanatory. You can rip all the excess code in the recording out of the macro.

Finally, You might have to make an app which intefaces with solidworks. Opens the file, Saves as an STL, closes the file. There are multiple languages you can use for this.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, SolidWorks Task Scheduler + conversion macro is the way to go